# Python 3.6 Installation in Spyder

Tags: python, package, spyder

I am currently using Using Spyder that is running off Python version 3.7, however I want to use a package (discord.py) that is only compatible with 3.6. Does anyone know how to install this version and get it running in Spyder instead of 3.7?

Answer (score 2):

Discord.py supports Python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8. So you don't need to change the python version to Python 3.6.

**Python 3.5.3 or higher is required**

More information:

- [discord.py @ PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/)
- [discord.py Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/)